# Dask.distributed cluster administration

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm setting up Dask Python cluster at work (30 machines, 8 cores each in average). People use only a portion of their CPU power, so `dask-workers` will be running on background at low priority. All workers are listening to `dask-scheduler` on my master node. It works perfect if only I who use it, however it's gonna be used by several people in a concurrent manner - so i need to be able to admin this cluster:

- Authenticate users, reject unknowns
- Identify who submitted which jobs
- Restrict number of submitted jobs per user
- Restrict timeout for computation per job
- Kill any job as admin

dask.distributed out of box provides a little of functionality described above. Could you please advice on some solution (may be hybrid Dask + something)?

Answer (score 0):

Usually people use a cluster manager like Kubernetes, Yarn, SLURM, SGE, PBS or something else.  That system handles user authentication, resource management, and so on.  A user then uses the one of the Dask-kubernetes, Dask-yarn, Dask-jobqueue projects to create their own short-lived scheduler and workers on the cluster on an as-needed basis.